# check for substring is not working

Tags: python

I want to check for a sub letter so I wrote this code (Python 2.7):

```
print text
if ('e' or 'E') in text:
    text = "%s"%float(text)
    print text
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877844/how-would-i-check-a-string-for-a-certain-letter-in-python).

text is a variable which changes, curently it has the value: `0E-7`

However this doesn't work.
When I debug it jumps over the if block.

Why the condition is false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your code is asking is "Is the value `('e' or 'E')` in `text`?" The when you evaluate `('e' or 'E')`, you get `'e'`. Here's the fix:

```
if ('e' in text) or ('E' in text):
```

Answer (score 1):

`('e' or 'E')` evaluates to `'e'`.  So you are testing `if 'e' in text:` which is not true here since the `E` in `0E-7` is uppercase.

Here you can see it interactively:

```
>>> text = '0E-7'                  # note that E is uppercase
>>> ('e' or 'E') in text           # why is this false?
False
>>> ('E' or 'e') in text           # but true here?
True
>>> ('e' or 'E')                   # aha! 'or' returns the first truthy value
'e'
>>> 'e' in text.lower()            # this fixes it
True
>>> any(c in text for c in 'eE')   # another possible fix
True
>>> not set(text).isdisjoint('eE') # yet another way to do it
True
```

Comment: ('e' or 'E') evaluates to 'e', since the `or` accepts the first value if it is "truthy"

Comment: @jcfollower:  Yeah, I can't believe I made that error.  That's what happens when you get banished to vbscript for months on end, you start inventing semantics that exist in neither language.

Answer (score 0):

`('e' or 'E')` is a boolean expression, and it is evaluated as `'e'`.

My suggestion is:

```
if any(char in text for char in ('e', 'E')):
    # ...
```